# Navigation item don't appear when I running the Simulator, although navigation bar appears on screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I added 2 *bar button items* on my main view controller and linked them into code. I also created outlet to *navigation item*. Although, when I run the iOS simulator none of my bar button items appear, but navigation bar appears. I also tried to repeat it from code, but got the same result. In setup *navigation bar* I also check **Translucent** - got the same result. In 3D model screen:

1. **navigation bar** -> **translucent** off
2. **navigation bar** -> **translucent** on

   Can someone help me?

[image: navigation bar setup]
[image: navigation item in controller and hierarchy view]
[image: on running Simulator without navigation item]
[image: 3D model screen(translusent off)]
[image: 3D model screen (translusent on)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: my problem hierarchy view controllers]
[image]

The problem was in the hierarchy view controllers. In my case hierarchy was:

> navigationVC -> tabBarVC -> myCustomVC ([my problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ledq.png))

To solve this problem, I changed it to:

> tabBarVC -> navigationVC -> myCustomVC ([my resolve problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiGdu.png))